# Calculate: $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}-1}{x^2-4}$

Tags: limits

After substituting $x$ with $y^2$ I obtain

$$\frac{y^2-2}{(y^2-2)^2}$$

and I'm not sure that this is the correct way of cancelling the square root,so can anyone help me with this problem please?

Comment: You can multiply top and bottom by top's conjugate. Also factor the $x^2 - 4$ on bottom.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Square root can easily be eliminated algebraically as far as the limit is concerned.

Comment: @DRF Silly me! Of course it can!

Answer (score 5):

If you put $y^2$ in place of $x$ you get $\sqrt{y^2-1}-1$ in the numerator.  This certainly is not $y^2-2$.

If you let $y=\sqrt{x-1}$ then you have $y^2=x-1$ and hence $x=y^2+1$.  As $x$ approaches $2$, $y$ approaches $1$.  So
$$
\lim_{x\to2} \frac{\sqrt{x-1}-1}{x^2-4} = \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y-1}{(y^2+1)^2-4}.
$$
Since this becomes $0/0$ as $y$ approaches $1$, you need to write
$$
\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y-1}{(y-1)(\cdots\cdots)} = \lim_{y\to 1}\frac 1 {(\cdots\cdots)}.
$$
Figure out how to complete that factorization and then go on from there.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}-1}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}-1}{(x-2)(x+2)}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}+1}{\sqrt{x-1}+1}=\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)
(\sqrt{x-1}+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{1}{(x+2)(\sqrt{x-1}+1)}=\frac{1}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well if you substitute $y^2=x$ then you should be getting $\lim_{y\to \sqrt 2} \frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}-1}{y^4-4}$ which is quite far from what you wrote.

What you might want to consider is multiplying top and bottom by conjugate of the top.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, I am under the impression you are unaware of L'Hopital's Rule.

If you have a indeterminate form only of the forms $\frac{ \infty }{ \infty }$ and $\frac{ 0 }{ 0}$ then you differentiate the numerator and denomitator in order to create a function that is able to be evaluated using limits, this is considered the value of the limit.

$$\frac{d}{dx}  \sqrt{x-1} -1= \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^{ \frac{-1}{2} } $$

And,

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^2+4)=2x$$

Then we must evaluate the following limit,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}  \frac{ (x-1)^{-1/2} }{4x}$$

So simple evaluation will tell us,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}  \frac{ (x-1)^{-1/2} }{4x} =  \pm  \frac{1}{8}$$

Hope I helped you evaluate this limit. You must be a undergraduate in Calculus I with little knowledge of L'Hopital's Rule and other secrets to evaluate complicated limits.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule might not be a good way to proceed.  A limit may arise in an exercise on finding a derivative by using the definition.  Then it becomes logically circular to use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I completely agree and I was indeed aware of this. But it does work for finding limits whose values are not functions.